# Hard contest type trigonometry proof

Tags: trigonometry

Suppose that real numbers $x, y, z$ satisfy:
$$\frac{\cos x + \cos y + \cos z}{\cos(x + y + z)}
=
\frac{\sin x + \sin y + \sin z}{\sin (x + y + z )}
= p$$

Then prove that:
$$\cos (x + y) + \cos (y + z ) + \cos (x + z) = p$$

I am not even getting where to start? Please help.

Comment: tried expanding $\cos (x + y) + \cos (y + z ) + \cos (x + z)$?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Yes, but then?

Comment: even if that was not helpful to you,if you can write that here some one can extend that to desired result...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I have expanded that and nothing else, which is very obvious to do.

Comment: Some observations, not sure if helpful  $$p^2\cos^2(x+y+z)=(\sum \cos x)^2=\sum\cos^2x+2\sum\cos x\cos y$$

$$p^2\sin^2(x+y+z)=(\sum \sin x)^2=\sum\sin^2x+2\sum\sin x\sin y$$

Adding we get  $$p^2=3+2\sum\cos(x-y)$$

On subtraction, $$p^2\cos(2x+2y+2z)=\sum\cos2x+2\sum \cos(x+y)$$

Comment: @Sawarnik, would you mind sharing the source of the Hard (the hardest I have met with recently)problem?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee  I have PDF called Trigonometry Problems, I don't remember the source but it contains 53 equally hard problems.

Comment: @Sawarnik,can you link your Trigonometry problems PDF? Thank you

Comment: @math110 http://ohkawa.cc.it-hiroshima.ac.jp/AoPS.pdf/Trigonometry%20Problems%20-%20Amir%20Hossein%20Parvardi.pdf

Comment: @Sawarnik, thanks a ton for the link. Some of the problems are already logged here:)

Comment: @Sawarnik,Thank you very much!

Comment: Does it mind if I post several more questions that I could not solve [infact most of the questions] as separate questions?

Comment: @Sawarnik, try to post independent problems in as separate questions

Answer (score 15, accepted):

note 
$$\cos{(x+y)}=\cos{[(x+y+z)-z]}=\cos{(x+y+z)}\cos{z}+\sin{(x+y+z)}\sin{z}$$
and 
$$\cos{(y+z)}=\cos{(x+y+z)}\cos{x}+\sin{(x+y+z)}\sin{x}$$
$$\cos{(z+x)}=\cos{(x+y+z)}\cos{y}+\sin{(x+y+z)}\sin{y}$$
add this three
\begin{align*}
&\cos{(x+y)}+\cos{(y+z)}+\cos{(x+z)}\\
&=(\cos{x}+\cos{y}+\cos{z})\cos{(x+y+z)}+(\sin{x}+\sin{y}+\sin{z})\sin{(x+y+z)}\\
&=p\cos^2{(x+y+z)}+p\sin^2{(x+y+z)}\\
&=p
\end{align*}

Comment: nice solution, this also solves another problem : $$\sum\sin(x+y)=0$$

Comment: Wow, this is really elegant!

Answer (score 6):

I prefer @math110's solution, but here's a brute force method using complex exponentials, 
with 
$$\cos \theta = \frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2} \qquad \sin\theta = \frac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{2i}$$
We define
$$a := e^{ix} \qquad b := e^{iy} \qquad c := e^{iz}$$
so that
$$p = \frac{\cos x + \cos y + \cos z}{\cos(x+y+z)} \implies p(a^2b^2c^2 +1) = abc (a+b+c) + bc + ca + ab \qquad (1)$$
$$p = \frac{\sin x + \sin y + \sin z}{\sin(x+y+z)} \implies p(a^2b^2c^2 - 1 ) = abc (a+b+c) - bc - ca - ab \qquad (2)$$

Thus, from $(1)-(2)$ and $(1)+(2)$, we have
$$p = bc + ca + ab \qquad\qquad p = \frac{a+b+c}{abc} = \frac{1}{bc}+\frac{1}{ca}+\frac{1}{ab}$$
whereupon
$$2p = bc+\frac{1}{bc}\;+\;ca+\frac{1}{ca}\;+\;ab+\frac{1}{ab} = 2\left( \cos(y+z)+\cos(z+x)+\cos(x+y)\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

Since
\begin{align*}
p \cos(x+y+z) &= \cos x + \cos y + \cos z \\
p \sin(x+y+z) &= \sin x + \sin y +\sin z
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
p e^{i(x+y+z)} & = e^{ix} + e^{iy} + e^{iz} 
\end{align*}
Multiplying throughout by $e^{-i(x+y+z)}$, we get
\begin{align*}
p = e^{-i(y+z)} + e^{-i(z+x)} + e^{-i(x+y)}
\end{align*}
Since $p$ is real, equating the real parts, we get
$$\cos(y+z) + \cos(z+x) + \cos(x+y) = p $$