# How can I find $\sum_{cyc}\sin x\sin y$

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry, polynomials, complex-numbers, substitution

$x$, $y$ & $z$ are real number such that

$$\frac{\sin{x}+\sin{y}+\sin{z}}{\sin{(x+y+z)}}=\frac{\cos{x}+\cos{y}+\cos{z}}{\cos{(x+y+z)}}=2$$

find the value

$$\sum_{cyc}\sin x\sin y$$

All help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571706/hard-contest-type-trigonometry-proof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the Blue's beautiful idea.

Let $e^{ix}=a$, $e^{iy}=b$ and $e^{iz}=c$.

Hence, $\sin{x}=\frac{a-\frac{1}{a}}{2i}=\frac{a^2-1}{2ai}$, $\cos{x}=\frac{a^2+1}{2a}$, $\sin{y}=\frac{b^2-1}{2bi}$, $\sin{x}=\frac{c^2-1}{2ci}$ and $\cos{x}=\frac{c^2+1}{2c}$.

Thus, $\sum\limits_{cyc}\sin{x}=2\sin(x+y+z)$ gives $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2bc-ab)=2(a^2b^2c^2-1)$ and

$\sum\limits_{cyc}\cos{x}=2\cos(x+y+z)$ gives $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2bc+ab)=2(a^2b^2c^2+1)$ or
$ab+ac+bc=2$ and $a+b+c=2abc$.

Thus, $$-\sum\limits_{cyc}\sin{x}\sin{y}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a^2-1)(b^2-1)}{4ab}=\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}c(a^2-1)(b^2-1)}{4abc}=$$
$$=\frac{abc(ab+ac+bc)-\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)+a+b+c}{4abc}=\frac{abc(ab+ac+bc)-(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)+3abc+a+b+c}{4abc}=\frac{1}{2}-1+\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{4}$$

Comment: Answer is $-3/4$?

Comment: @Muralidharan I just missed that $i^2=-1$. I fixed my post. Thank you!

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg -- I like your method, but there must be some error -- the correct answer is $-3/4$, not $3/4$.

Comment: really beautiful!! (+1), $\,\color{red}{-}\sum\limits_{cyc}\sin{x}\sin{y}=\frac34\Rightarrow\sum\limits_{cyc}\sin{x}\sin{y}=\color{red}{-}\frac34\,$.

Comment: It's such beautiful solution.
thank you, sir.

Answer (score 3):

Since
\begin{align*}
2 \cos(x+y+z) &= \cos x + \cos y + \cos z \\
2 \sin(x+y+z) &= \sin x + \sin y +\sin z
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
2 e^{i(x+y+z)} & = e^{ix} + e^{iy} + e^{iz} 
\end{align*}
Multiplying throughout by $e^{-ix}$, we get
\begin{align*}
2e^{i(y+z)} = 1 + e^{i(y-x)} + e^{i(z-x)} 
\end{align*}
Equating the real  parts,  we get
\begin{align*}
2\cos(y+z) &= 1 + \cos(y-x) +\cos(z-x)\\
2(\cos y \cos z - \sin y \sin z) & = 1 + \cos x \cos y + \sin x \sin y + \cos z \cos x + \sin z \sin x
\end{align*}
Similarly, we get
\begin{align*}
2(\cos x \cos z - \sin x \sin z) &= 1 + \cos x \cos y + \sin x \sin y + \cos z \cos y + \sin z \sin y\\
2(\cos x \cos y - \sin x \sin y) &= 1 + \cos x \cos z + \sin x \sin z+ \cos z \cos y + \sin z \sin y\\
\end{align*}
Adding, and canceling $2 \sum \cos x \cos y$ from the sides, we get
$$\sum \sin x \sin y = -\frac{3}{4}$$

Comment: Thank you for your solution, sir.